# How to correctly chain OR and AND conditions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to write

```
if (x !== "One" || x !== "Two" || x !== "Three") {
   x = undefined;
}
```

However, this is not working for me. What is the correct way to get the same result?

It works fine when I only have one condition

```
if (x !== "One") {
   x = undefined;
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to set a variable called `var` to something? `var` is a keyword?

Comment: Can you explain, *in words*, when you want the `if` statement to run?  When it's none of these?  P.S. You can't name a variable `var`.

Comment: You probably want `if(!(var == 'One' || var == 'Two'))`, which by DeMorgan's Law is `if(var != 'One' && var != 'Two')`.   You can also simplify this by using an array `if(['One', 'Two'].indexOf(var) === -1)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wanted an and, not an or. And your variable name can't be `var`.

```
var t = "One";
if (t !== "One" && t !== "Two" && t !== "Three") {
  t = undefined;
}
```

Because the previous or(s) would always evaluate to `true`. if the variable was "a" or var was "One" it's not "Two" or "Three".

Comment: You're totally right. Thanks for such a quick reply.

Comment: @neli I always try to appreciate *constructive* criticism.